# scanf("%c") call seems to be skipped

Tags: c, scanf

I tried this code below, but it seems `scanf("%c")` is skipped. It only asks me to enter name and age and skips the lines below that. It just print the text in the `printf` above the `if` statements. Can anyone help?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    char sex;
    char name[20];
    char status;
    printf("Enter your last name\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Enter your age\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Enter sex (M/F)\n");
    scanf("%c", &sex);

    printf("your status,married, single,irrelevant (M/S/I)\n");
    scanf("%c", &status);
    if(age>=16 && sex=='M')
        printf("hello, Mr %s\n", name);
    if(age<16 && sex =='M')
        printf("hello, Master %s\n", name);
    if(sex=='F' && status=='M')
        printf("hello, Mrs %s\n", name);
    if(sex=='F' &&(status=='S' ||status=='I'))
        printf("hello,miss %s\n", name);
}
```

Comment: Unless you are interested in whitespace like newlines, do not use `%c`. Simply use the string conversion `%s` and use the first character of the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &sex);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &sex);
       ^
      space
```

and

```
scanf("%c", &status);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &status);
       ^
      space
```

The problem is because of trailing newline characters after your second call to `scanf()`. Since it is of `%d` type specifier, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> A newline character ( `'\n'` ) is left in the stream and the next `scanf()` tries to read that newline character, and thus, it seems as though it just skipped input, but in fact, it read the newline character.

So, the newline character is stored in the variable `sex`, and thus, it skips asking you for input for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are interested in whitespace like newlines, do not use `%c`. Simply use the string conversion `%s` and use the first character of the input.

Rationale: All `scanf` conversion specifiers except `%c` ignore white space including newlines. They are designed to read sequences of input tokens (numbers, words) where the amount and nature of white space is irrelevant. The words can all be on the same line, or each word on a different line; `scanf` wouldn't care unless you force single character reads with `%c` which is almost never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
#include<stdio.h>
int  main()
{
int age;
char sex;
char name[20];
char status;
printf("Enter your last name\n");
// scanf("%s", &name);
fgets(name,20,stdin);

printf("Enter your age\n");
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("Enter sex (M/F)\n");
scanf(" %c", &sex);


printf("your status,married, single,irrelevant (M/S/I)\n");
scanf(" %c", &status);
if(age>=16 && sex=='M')
printf("hello, Mr %s\n", name);
if(age<16 && sex =='M')
printf("hello, Master %s\n", name);
if(sex=='F' && status=='M')
printf("hello, Mrs %s\n", name);
if(sex=='F' &&(status=='S' ||status=='I'))
printf("hello,miss %s\n", name);
return 0;
}
```

Here, I have added an extra space before the format specifier `%c`, to accommodate any previous input like newline (\n). 
Another alternative method is to use `getchar()` immediately before you take any character input.

Also, if you perform string input with `scanf`,  it will not read the input after encountering a whitespace. So, instead use `fgets` for taking any string input which might contain spaces.

Another thing I changed in your code (trivial) is `int main()` and `return 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because blankspace is also treated as a character and and happens when you press enter.
So Leave a space.

```
scanf(" %c",&something);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following for all `scanf`s.

```
scanf("%c\n",&smth);
```

And then enter the values one by one separating them by newlines (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

This helped me too when I had the same problem.

```
scanf("%c*",&smth);
```

That makes `scanf` skip any other characters that a user might input, including newlines.

---

**Note**: use appropriate format strings for each type (`%s` for strings, `%d` for integers, etc).