# C Programming Rock-Paper-Scissors Not Working

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with this C Programming activity. I'm new to C-Programming and would really like to ask you guys for your help. So please bear with me.

So here's the problem...

When I run the program as I enter my choice for Player Two the program automatically stops and closes. It wont even let me press "ENTER" before it closes. I tried everything else I can and looked for a solution online but to no avail. I am only allowed to use the conditional statement If-Else for this. I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
clrscr();
char one, two;

printf("\t\t\t      Rock-Paper-Scissors\n");
printf("Choose from the following:\n");
printf("r for Rock\np for Paper\ns for Scissors\n\n");
printf("Player One enter your choice: ");
scanf("%c",&one);
printf("Player Two enter your choice: ");
scanf("%c",&two);
printf("\n");


//rock over scissors
if (one == 'r' && two == 's'){
    printf("Rock Destroys Scissors\n");
    printf("Player One Wins!");
}
else if (two == 'r' && one == 's'){
    printf("Rock Destroys Scissors\n");
    printf("Player Two Wins!");
}
//paper over rock
else if (one == 'p' && two == 'r'){
    printf("Paper Covers Rock\n");
    printf("Player One Wins!");
}
else if (two == 'p' && one == 'r'){
    printf("Paper Covers Rock\n");
    printf("Player Two Wins!");
}
//scissors over paper
else if (one == 's' && two == 'p'){
    printf("Scissors Cut Paper\n");
    printf("Player One Wins!");
}
else if (two == 's' && one == 'p'){
    printf("Scissors Cut Paper\n");
    printf("Player Two Wins!");
}
else
    printf("It's a Tie!");
getch();
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent moment to start learning how to use your debugger!

Comment: Try `scanf(" ") /* consume whitespace */;` (the "format string" contains a single space) to consume optional whitespace in the input buffer.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `scanf("%c",&one);` to `scanf(" %c",&one);` and `scanf("%c",&two);` to      `scanf(" %c",&two);`

[scanf function seems to be skipped in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775323/scanf-function-seems-to-be-skipped-in-c)

Comment: Thanks a lot @suvojit_007 . As I said I'm a newb in C and have no idea whatsoever what to do with it so thanks a lot for answering.